# PHP: CURL PUT FOR Https Url not working as fopen fails

Tags: php, curl, https, put

I want to upload the image to the url using Curl.
But as the Image file is  on https url i am not able to read the file using fopen.

Code is as below.

```
$file = "https://xyz.com/image.jpg";
$url = "http://abc.com/upload.php";

$fp = fopen($file, "r");
$headers = array("Content-Type: xml");
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($file));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$responseInfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Let me see. My magic crystal ball is telling me that we have new moon and that's why your code does not work. Seriously, please add the error message you're seeing to your question.

Answer (score 2):

I think that this should work assuming that you don't need to pass the file data that you're uploading in as a named key/value pair.

```
$file = "https://xyz.com/image.jpg";
$url = "http://abc.com/upload.php";

$fileData = file_get_contents($file);

$fp = fopen($file, "r");
$headers = array("Content-Type: xml");
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fileData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$responseInfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
```

opt setting for PUT API request will work fine on using this setting below:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
```